# НЕ могу разобраться с блоками div

Tags: html, bootstrap

Совсем недавно начал изучать блоки и пока не совсем понимаю. Задача такова: Нужно создать блок, в нем еще 2 блока, и выравнять их так, чтобы они занимали одинаковое место. У меня же получается так, что блоки стоят друг под другом.
В чем заключается ошибка ?  [image: Мой результат]

А вот код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32" role="img" aria-label="Bootstrap"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Информация</a></li>


      <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
        <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn-danger">Источник</button>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 offset-1">
        <h1>Погода в вашем городе</h1>
        <form action="">
          <label for="city">Город</label>
          <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Введите город">
          <input type="submit" name="send" value="узнать" class="mt-2 btn-danger">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 offset -1">
      <h1>Информация о погоде</h1>
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-9">
            <b>Город</b>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы колонку `.col-5.offset-1` вынесли из строки `.row`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32" role="img" aria-label="Bootstrap"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Информация</a></li>


      <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
        <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn-danger">Источник</button>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5 offset-1">
        <h1>Погода в вашем городе</h1>
        <form action="">
          <label for="city">Город</label>
          <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Введите город">
          <input type="submit" name="send" value="узнать" class="mt-2 btn-danger">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5 offset-1"> <!-- плюс тут кривость была из-за того, что тут было 'offset -1'-->
        <h1>Информация о погоде</h1>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9">
              <b>Город</b>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```